# Excel vba loop through table

Tags: excel, vba, loops

What i want to do is to loop through the rows of a table, And checking each row in a column for duplicates.

For example I will start with cell A2, say it has a text value of "CAP". I want to compare that value "CAP" with all of the other rows in that Column.

If it finds a Duplicate i want it to put in the Column dupe "Dupe1" so both records have the same dupe number.

Then it moves to A3 and checks that value with all of the other rows in that column. so on so on.

If more dupes are found then they are names "Dupe2", "Dupe3" etc...

I am struggling to figure out how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Use a helper column with a `=COUNTIF()` formula?

Comment: A little code would help to show your level of knowledge. Are you simply looping with Cell references or through table references  or my personal favorite import to array and loop.

Comment: I was looking at looping through the tables row.count but couldn't see a way of reading the text in the row. I've used recordsets in access but I'm presuming it can't be done like that through excel?

Answer (score 1):

```
For Example, you have two columns:

Column A | Dupe 
1 
2 
3 
4 
4 
5 
4

Sub Button1_Click()
    n = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 1
    Duplicate = 0
        For i = 2 To n
            If Len(Trim(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2))) = 0 Then
                For j = i + 1 To n
                    If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 1) Then
                       Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2) = "Dupe" + CStr(Counter)
                       Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 2) = "Dupe" + CStr(Counter)
                       Duplicate = 1
                    End If
                Next j
             End If
             If Duplicate = 1 Then
                Counter = Counter + 1
                Duplicate = 0
             End If
        Next i
End Sub
```